# Django S3BotoStorage __init__ override error , "has no attribute 'rsplit'"

Tags: python, django, boto, django-storage

The last lines of the trace:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 328, in get_storage_class
    return import_string(import_path or settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 15, in import_string
    module_path, class_name = dotted_path.rsplit('.', 1)
AttributeError: type object 'S3StaticStorage' has no attribute 'rsplit'
```

`S3StaticStorage`:

```
class S3StaticStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['bucket'] = getattr(settings, 'AWS_BUCKET_STATIC')
        super(S3StaticStorage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I have a file called `prod.py` which imports `common.py`, and this is configured accordingly as the settings source in `wsgi.py` and `manage.py`. A line in `prod.py` sets the bucket name:

```
AWS_BUCKET_STATIC = 'myproject-static'
```

This was not a problem without the override, when I was putting everything in one bucket. Do I need to import `rsplit` when using this class or something? It looks like it should be in-built to Python so wouldn't need an import. If I understood it correctly, `getattr(settings, 'AWS_BUCKET_STATIC')` would get the variable from whatever settings files Django finds, so that shouldn't be a problem either.

---

Full trace:

```
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 342, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 195, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 40, in load_command_class
    return module.Command()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.storage.path('')
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 204, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 394, in _setup
    self._wrapped = get_storage_class(settings.STATICFILES_STORAGE)()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 328, in get_storage_class
    return import_string(import_path or settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 15, in import_string
    module_path, class_name = dotted_path.rsplit('.', 1)
AttributeError: type object 'S3StaticStorage' has no attribute 'rsplit'
```

Comment: how are you using registering `S3StaticStorage` in your settings?

Comment: In `prod.py`, `AWS_BUCKET_STATIC = 'myproject-static'` and `STATICFILES_STORAGE = S3StaticStorage`. I'm importing `S3StaticStorage` from `storage.py`, which has the actual class override code shown in OP. The same rsplit error occurs when running `collectstatic`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It [looks like](https://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) `STATICFILES_STORAGE` is expecting a string representing the module path:

`STATICFILES_STORAGE='path.to.your.S3StaticStorage'`

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Do you know why it must be a string/why the other approach doesn't work?

Comment: i'm not sure why but it can help support lazy loading and settings overrides